# Data across multiple years using Sequelize.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to find the month-wise data for multiple years in Sequelize.js

```
For eg.Stardate:2016-01-01 and EndDate:2017-02-29.
table1
date           pack_price
2016-01-01         30
2016-02-19         30
2016-03-14         20
2016-10-01         50
2017-01-28         100
2017-02-25         29

Expected Answer:
date          pack_price
Jan 2016           30
Feb 2016           30
Mar 2016           20
Oct 2016           50
Jan 2017           100
Feb 2017            29

Actual Answer
Date      Pack_price
Jan 2016     130
Feb 2016     59
Mar 2016     20
Oct 2016     50
```

Node js code using Sequelize.js

```
Utils.table1.findAll({
        where:{
            tran_date: {
               [Op.gt]: startTime,
               [Op.lt]: endTime
            }
         },
         attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('sum', Sequelize.col('pack_price')),'total'],[Sequelize.fn('month', Sequelize.col('tran_date')),'Month']],
         group:[[Sequelize.fn('month', Sequelize.col('tran_date'))]],
         raw: true,


    }).then(total=>{
        Utils.sendResponse(1, total, "success", q)

       })
```

However, this works well for one year.Should work for multiple years.Do you have any idea how I could make this happen?.Thanks in advance.